# Locate VHost files in CentOS

Tags: vhost

I was just given a server and need to configure some Vhosts files.

They have no idea where are they anymore.

How do I locate them?

Comment: Are you talking about apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's an Apache webserver, take a look in `/etc/httpd/`:

```
grep -r VirtualHost /etc/httpd/*
```